# How can I make the Terminal compile a file I edited using Aquamacs?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, terminal, compile, aquamacs

I'm having trouble getting a small source code compiled in the terminal. I'm completely new at this (just started taking an introductory course)... I'm going to try to describe the situation as best I can, so bear with me.

This is what I've done:

I opened Aquamacs and started working on a new file I called "CerealBox". I noticed the words were not in colors, so I started poking around until I found a setting to change the buffer to C++ mode. Then, I had the colors..

So I wrote the source code and I'm pretty sure I have everything done right (my professor wrote this out step by step on the board and I only copied it onto the editor).

I go to the terminal and type in

```
g++ -Wall -c CerealBox.cpp
```

as instructed to me by my professor, and the thing answers back saying

> "No such file or directory"
>
> "No input files".

I have no idea what to do! Nobody in my class uses Mac OS, so they're no help! Please, help if you can!

PS: When I save the CerealBox file, it turns up in finder as a blank page icon with the name CerealBox under it. When I click on it, I get a small window with the source code in black text. Shouldn't this be opening up with Aquamacs when I click on it? Is that my mistake?

Another thing, why is Aquamacs not running on C++ from the start, I mean, why don't I get the colorful words right when I start it up? I don't think I had that problem last time I used it.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  int weight_in_oz, boxes_per_ton;
  double oz_per_ton = 35273.92, weight_in_tons;

  cout << "What is the weight in ounces per box of cereal?\n";
  cin >> weight_in_oz;

  weight_in_tons = weight_in_oz / oz_per_ton;
  boxes_per_ton = oz_per_ton / weight_in_oz;

  cout << "If you have a box of cereal that weighs "
    cout << weight_in_oz << " ounces, then in weighs "
    cout << weight_in_tons << " metric tons and you need "
    cout << boxes_per_ton << " boxes to complete one metric ton.\n";

  return 0;
}

Comment: That is the source code I'm trying to compile... I wrote ".cpp" at the end of the name and it keeps telling me I have a mistake. It says: 167-206-54-24-dynamic:~ andreagarcia$ g++ -Wall -c CerealBox.cpp
CerealBox.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
CerealBox.cpp:17: error: expected `;' before ‘cout’

Answer (score 0):

If your file is called `CerealBox` (and not `CerealBox.cpp`), then you should rename the file to `CerealBox.cpp` first to make it clear that it's a C++ source file.

Then try again:

```
g++ -Wall -c CerealBox.cpp
```

For `g++` it wouldn't really matter how the file's called, but …

> why is aquamacs not running on C++ form the start, I mean, why don't I get the colorful words right when I start it up?

This is exactly because it doesn't know the file is a C++ source file. AFAIK, there's no language guessing or automatic syntax highlighting based on the contents alone. You need the extension for that.